# How to use topclient in taobao in node js

Tags: node.js, sdk, openapi

I have taken reference from few sites

1. [node js topclient](https://doc.open.alipay.com/doc2/apiDetail.htm?apiId=24615&scopeId=274)
2. [taobao node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/taobao)
3. [node-taobao-topclient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-taobao-topclient)

**What I did:**

I installed **node-taobao-topclient**

My code:

```
TopClient = require('node-taobao-topclient');
const client  = new TopClient({
    'appkey': 'xxxx',
    'appsecret': 'xxxxx',
    'REST_URL': 'http://gw.api.taobao.com/router/rest'
});

client.execute('taobao.wlb.imports.general.consign', {
    "session" : "620260160ZZ61473fc31270a2c1f5dcc0efdff78b4c58312482635690",
    'trade_order_id':'245033103766976',
    'resource_id':'5044440108577',
    'store_code':'Tran_Store_775585',
    'first_logistics':'123',
    'first_waybillno':'123',
    'sender_id':'228',
    'cancel_id':'228'
}, function(error, response) {
    if (!error) console.log(response);
    else console.log(error);
})
```

**When I run above code I get error :**

> TypeError: TopClient is not a constructor

As I am new to node I don't how to exactly use such packages as on reference websites they are using it like:

```
TopClient = require('./topClient').TopClient;
```

My node-taobao-topclient package looks like below:

[image: node-taobao-topclient]

Any guidance on how I can use this API in node would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have used for instalation :

```
npm i taobao-topclient
```

I have a correct compilation with :

```
const TopClient = require('taobao-topclient');

const client = new TopClient({
    'appkey': aliexpress_app_key,
    'appsecret': aliexpress_app_secret,
    'REST_URL': 'http://gw.api.taobao.com/router/rest'
    });
```

I have read the library and they do an exports directly from TopClient, so is not necesary to call it again , in the library at the top :

```
const request = require('request')
const util = require('./topUtil')

module.exports = class TopClient {
  constructor (options) {
    const opts = options || {}
    if (!opts.appkey || !opts.appsecret) {
...............
```

If you call it again with another point .TopClient, dont found anything.

Comment: Hi Javier Tomas, thanks for your answer but it's been almost 4 years and I don't have source code to test your solution and mark it as correct.
Hopefully, this helps someone else!

Answer (score -1):

The following fragament works well:

```
TopClient = require('node-taobao-topclient').default;
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)

Comment: You can search the souce codes by yourself and have a look at what this package really exports. This is the way to answer the question.

Comment: The document of this package may be outdated, I think.